# Method of characteristics PDE $u_t +uu_x = x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

In this question you are asked to solve the initial value problem
\begin{aligned}
u_t +uu_x &= x,\\
u(x, 0) &= f(x)
\end{aligned}
using the method of characteristics. Using the parameters $s$ and $τ$, show that the solution can be expressed as

$$u(s, τ ) = \frac{1}{2}(f(s) + s) e^τ +\frac{1}{2}
(f(s) − s) e
^{−τ}$$

I tried using Method of characteristics but cannot get the answer.

$\frac{dt}{ds} = 1$, $ \frac{dx}{ds} =u$ and $\frac{du}{ds} =x$.

This gives $\frac{dx}{du} =x/u
$ which does not give the solution as above. How do i get the above solution. Thanks.

Comment: $u(s, τ ) = 12(f(s) + s) e^τ +12(f(s) − s) e^{−τ}$ is absurd. Probably there is a typo.

Comment: Yep you are right. Fixed. @JJacquelin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us apply the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

- $\frac{\text d t}{\text d \tau} = 1$, letting $t(0)=0$, we know $t=\tau$.
- $\frac{\text d x}{\text d \tau} = u$ and $\frac{\text d u}{\text d \tau} = x$, so that $\frac{\text d^2 x}{\text d \tau^2} = \frac{\text d}{\text d \tau}\frac{\text d x}{\text d \tau} = \frac{\text d u}{\text d \tau}$, i.e., $\frac{\text d^2 x}{\text d \tau^2} = x$. Letting $(x(0),u(0)) = (s,f(s))$, we know
  \begin{aligned} x(\tau) &=
     \frac{1}{2}(f(s)+s) e^\tau - \frac{1}{2}(f(s)-s) e^{-\tau}\\
        &= f(s) \sinh\tau + s\cosh\tau \, ,
  \end{aligned}
  and
  \begin{aligned}
     u(x(\tau),\tau) &= \frac{1}{2}(f(s)+s) e^\tau + \frac{1}{2}(f(s) - s)
     e^{-\tau} \\
       &= f(s) \cosh\tau + s\sinh\tau \, .
  \end{aligned}

To obtain $u(x, t)$, one eliminates $s$ by using the expression of $x(\tau)$. Here, it is hard to express $s$ in terms of $x(\tau)$ and $\tau$ for general initial data $f$, but it is possible in some particular cases. For instance, if $f(s) = a s$, then
$$
u(x,t)= x \frac{a+\tanh t}{1 + a\tanh t}
$$
as long as $t \neq \text{argtanh}(-1/a)$.

Comment: Could you explain how you arrived at $\frac{d^2 x}{d\tau^2}=x$? I shall put a bounty on this question if you wish.

Comment: @Stuart-JamesBurney Done, answer edited.